# CRM 2011 - Reports not updating

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, ssrs-2008-r2

I made a change to a report today that displays some financial data - it was being displayed incorrectly so I made a change to ensure it displays the correct data.

In Visual Studio the data is now correct when I run the ssrs report but when I import the report into CRM 2011 the data is still showing incorrectly as it did before.

I have checked and rechecked that the report is pointing at the same database in both instances.

I have tried everything I can think of:

- Removing the field and then re-adding it
- Changing the name of the field
- Removing hyperlinks that were in the report
- Removing a child report that was linked to the report

Any ideas what else I can try?

Comment: And when you change some static data on the report (like a title for example) are this changes show in CRM or not? Are you running this report from an entity form or report list?

Answer (score 0):

Really sorry to bother everybody!

It was a date issue - my local PC date is set to UK date whereas for some reason our CRM database is set to US date.